# Cannot find module 'meteor-promise'

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using Meteor 1.4.3.2 on a windows7 dev environment. 
I've ran into a problem with an application after attempting to remove a failed demeteorizer attempt. After removal of demeteorizer folders/files now receiving error:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'meteor-promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\muser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-
tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\tool-env\install-promise.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I believe this meteor-promise is related to the Fibers module used in demeteorizer. 
Seems that files were inadvertently removed from outside of application folders due to sym-link to somewhere in \AppData\Local.meteor....  I think.

My other applications are still working fine, so a meteor reinstall seems unlikely to fix issue.

Adding to the excitement none of my saved versions (including fresh clones from repo) will work either. This I think adds evidence to the sym-link theory.

Any suggestions on best approach to fix the application?

Thanks very much for your time and expertise.

Comment: If you think it's a symlink problem, you should try `meteor reset` to see if it rebuilds correctly

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Frederick. HOwever this also results in the exception. Any of the 'meteor' commands now result in this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like quite a mess, hopefully this fixes your issue.

Delete the `meteor-tool` folder within the version of meteor your app is using.  You mentioned you are using 1.4.3.2 so the folder to delete is probably...

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.3_2
```

You can double check by looking at the `release` file in your project's `.meteor` folder.

Once that is deleted, startup your meteor app using `meteor run` and it will detect that the `meteor-tool` version is missing and re-download it.  The `promise` package is installed inside this folder...so re-downloading will replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input @jordanwillis!

Absolutely a mess. Points out that while I've been happily coding along with Meteor I've neglected understanding what's under the hood.
Turns out this app was using 1.4.0, not 1.4.3 as I previously stated.

Here are the actions I took which fixed my problem.

Remove folders:

```
C:\Users\muser\testApp\.meteor\local\dev_bundle*\*
C:\Users\muser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\*
```

Ran:

```
C:\Users\muser\testApp> meteor run
```

Meteor re-installed 1.4.0-1 and did not try to recreate the dev_bundle folder which I assume was only needed for demeteorizer.
The application started up and all seems good.

Thanks again.